# Angular@13 formGroup values are null (reactive forms)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

Been trying to access form instance values bt they are all null..It worked fine in tempalate driven forms. I have imported ReactiveFormsModule. I have played around with the attr but I cant find what am missing??
The form is invalid the moment I use Validators.required meaning its empty

.component.html

```
<form [formGroup] ="tryForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" >
<div class="form-group">
<label>Name</label><br>
<input type="text" FormControlName ="name">
<span *ngIf="tryForm.invalid">Name required</span>
</div>
<!-- <div *ngIf="name.invalid" class="alert alert-danger"></div> -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Email</label><br>
    <input type="text" FormControlName ="email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Message</label><br>
    <input type="text" FormControlName ="message">
</div>
<button type = "submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl,FormGroup,Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { Router} from '@angular/router'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-log-in',
  templateUrl: './log-in.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./log-in.component.css']
})
export class LogInComponent implements OnInit {
  tryForm = this.fb.group({
    name : [''],
    email:  [''],
    message: [''],

  });

  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder,
      private router: Router) { }

  onSubmit(){
    if (this.tryForm.status == "VALID"){
      alert("Form Submitted Successfully.")
      alert(this.tryForm.get("name")?.value);
      this.tryForm.reset();
```

Comment: I think you have to change "FormControlName" to "formControlName" in template.

Comment: I have done that nothing is happening...even with brackets on

Comment: Look at example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sjfpej?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this `<input type="text" FormControlName ="email">` to this;

```
<input type="text" formControlName="email">
```

and build your form on ngOnInit,

```
ngOnInit(){
this.tryForm = this.fb.group({
    name : [''],
    email:  [''],
    message: [''],

  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

first you need to change the html `FormControlName` to `formControlName`. you can read the full explanation [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="tryForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(tryForm.value)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label><br />
    <input type="text" formControlName="name" />
    <span *ngIf="tryForm.invalid">Name required</span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email</label><br />
    <input type="text" formControlName="email" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Message</label><br />
    <input type="text" formControlName="message" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

after that change your ts like bellow, make sure you initialize the form on `ngOnInit`.

TS

```
export class LogInComponent implements OnInit {

  tryForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.tryForm = this.fb.group({
      name   : [''],
      email  : [''],
      message: [''],
    });
  }

  onSubmit(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

I replicate your code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-srkfey?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)